# Reactor Flux mergeWith using previous values

Tags: java, reactor

Is there any way to create a Flux by merging multiple Mono, the merged Mono is reading the value of the previous response.

Something like that :

```
Flux<Integer> values = Mono.just(1).mergeWith( value -> Mono.just(value * 2));
```

Comment: It is still a mono though if you merge it like that. Not sure what you want to achieve here. It could be a flux if you combine them both, but then the second cant be based on the result of the first mono. So do you want to have a stream with one value (what u did, but then its `Mono`) or with two independent values?

Comment: You have flatMapIterable/flatMapMany that could help, for ex `.flatMapIterable(v -> List.of(v, v*2))`.

Comment: @sp00m flatMapMany did the job. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `flatMapIterable`/`flatMapMany` that could help, for ex:

```
.flatMapIterable(v -> List.of(v, v*2))
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity and to illustrate sp00m answer, here is an example of how I use this technique in combination with recursion to call Youtube API and navigate throw all the response pages.

The next page id is given in the current page in the getNextPagetoken()

```
    public Flux<VideoListResponse> getvideoListResponses() {
        Videos.List request = ...
        return videoListResponseFluxPaginated(request, null, true);
    }

    private Flux<VideoListResponse> videoListResponseFluxPaginated(Videos.List request, String pageToken, boolean firstCall) {
        if(pageToken == null && !firstCall) return Flux.empty();
        request.setPageToken(pageToken);
        return Mono.fromCallable(request::execute)
            .flatMapMany(videoListResponse -> Flux.merge(Flux.just(videoListResponse), videoListResponseFluxPaginated(request, videoListResponse.getNextPageToken(),false)))
            ;
    }
```